Green’s function and Dirichlet problem
I have been studying Green's Functions for Laplace Equation and have some queries on a few things:

In Strauss's Book, the solution to the Dirichlet Problem is:
$$
u(\bf x_0) =
\iint_{\partial D} u(\bf{x})
\frac{\partial G(\bf{x},\bf{x_0})}{\partial n} \,dS\label{1}\tag{1}
$$

Suppose $D$ is a multiply connected region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with mutually non-interesting circular boundaries, say, $C_1, \dotsc, C_k$ such that $C_j$ is contained interior of region bounded by $C_1$ for all $j=2, \dotsc, k$.

Can the solution in $(1)$ be written as
\begin{align}
& u(\bf x_0)
\\[2mm] = & \
\int_{C_1} u(\bf{x})\frac{\partial G(\bf{x},\bf{x_0})}{\partial n} \,dx+ \dotsc + \int_{C_k} u(\bf{x})\frac{\partial G(\bf{x},\bf{x_0})}{\partial n} \,dx\ ?.
\end{align}

Also, $dS$ is suppose to be the area measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For planar domains, I guess it is just simply a line integral or one -dimensional length measure.

Am I missing something here, but I cannot pinpoint what exactly. Is the later one the correct one ?. Are they equivalent ?.


